# unable to compile my code

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a C++ code but I don't achieve to compile with `-static`. Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optimization.h>

int main(){

std::cout << opti::minimize(1,2) << std::endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

And when I type on the terminal :

```
g++ main.cpp -loptimization -std=c++11
```

it works but when I type :

```
g++ main.cpp -loptimization -static -std=c++11
```

it does not work I don't understand at all why ?

I got this :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loptimization
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What error did you get? post it verbose

Comment: Wich OS/linux version do you have?

Comment: I have Linux Mint

Comment: Shared object is .so, static is .a.  Do you have a liboptimization.a?

Comment: @FranklinWalker I can't locate liboptimization in google is this a library that came with the system o did you compile youself?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC16):

> #### `-static`
>
> On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no
>   effect. (...)

This means you probably do not have the static version of the library installed. You should check `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`. Dynamic libraries end in `.so` while static libraries end in `.a`.

Answer (score -2):

Edit :
Sometimes the orders of option for g++ or gcc compiler are important (I mean, I already get this kind of trouble with linked library), then I think you should try in other order, like this :

```
g++ -static -std=c++11 main.cpp -loptimization
```

or

```
g++ -static -loptimization -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Comment: I got /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loptimization
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I think you don't have the lib optimization
Try

    sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
and change 

    #include <dlib/optimization.h>

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that... I am gonna edit my answer!